# Setting cloud resource tag in helm chart

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am in the process of learning Helm charts and I have encountered a situation where I  cannot create Azure resources in my cluster (ingress external IP address for example) because it fails a specific policy. We have an azure policy that requires any created cloud resource to have a specific tag.

Is it possible to set a tag for the underlying cloud resource in a helm chart?

And if so, how?

Comment: As a general rule, no; Kubernetes objects don't directly represent cloud resources.  There might be a way (probably via annotations) but it would depend on the specific object and the controller that's creating it.

Comment: No way to do it, as far as I'm aware. I'm wondering if you can modify the policy to automatically add the tag (effect: modify)

Answer (score 1):

For helm charts that create a direct underlying cloud resource, such as an external IP address on an ingress, it appears there is no way to create tags. This is a challenge if you have policies that require tags to identify owner or create or whatever.  In this case the service staying in `<pending>` mode and a `kubectl get events --all-namespaces` shows the policy failure.

The work around I have been able to find (but still have to test) is to create the resource `a priori` and assign the tag, either using the portal, CLI, or Terraform. Then when you deploy the helm chart you use an override in a values.yaml.

Such as:

`helm install nginx-ingress --set service.loadBalancerIP=<my ip>`

I still have to figure out the details of how if Terraform creates the IP then I take the generated value programmatically and plant it in a values.html but I will burn that bridge when I get to it. =)

Thanks to all who responded.

This question is the reference: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3560